# Migrate MySQL to PostgreSql and share tables

Tags: mysql, postgresql, migration

I want to use PgSql in my new proyect, but I have old tables I need to use. Which is the best way to share tables between both databases? Is there any way of synchronizing several tables between databases?

Comment: I guess you need this https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLWays that convert T/SQL stored procedure, function, trigger, database schema (DDL) and data from Microsoft SQL Server to PostgreSQL.
See this link : [Migrate from MySQL  to PostgreSQL](http://www.ispirer.it/products/sql-server-to-postgresql-migration)
or
[Full Convert 6.4](https://www.spectralcore.com/fullconvert/howto-it/sql-to-postgres)

You can find more solutions at Database Administrator or ServerFault.

See this: [Dba Administrator](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15769/how-to-convert-a-mysql-database-to-postgresql/23172#23172)

Comment: Could you read the title please?I've said from Mysql. But thx for helping